# Zend Framwork 2 phpunit testing mock Identity object with acl permissions

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, zend-framework2, acl

How can I test those controller that are in acl.

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An exception was raised while creating "acl"; no instance returned
```

My Code for mocking

```
protected function mockLogin()
{
    $authService = $this->getMock('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');

    $authService->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getIdentity')
        ->will($this->returnValue(1));

    $authService->expects($this->any())
        ->method('hasIdentity')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $authService->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRole')
        ->will($this->returnValue(2));
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(true);
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setService('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService',
        $authService);
}

public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $this->mockLogin();
    $this->dispatch('/');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
    $this->assertModuleName('Application');
    $this->assertControllerName('Application\Controller\Index');
    $this->assertControllerClass('IndexController');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('application');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling the constructor of the `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService`?  By default that is being called, so that is likely a reason you are getting the exception.  Try `$this->getMock('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService', [], [], '', false);`

Comment: Beware when creating mock. Take care to initialize correctly your mock by injecting mock dependencies, disabling default constructor call, etc...

Comment: Hi! Sorry can you try to replace $authService = $this->getMock('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService'); with $authService = $this->getMock('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface'); Thansk! I don't know if this solution works.. thanks